# ng-animate: only add to the dom after the animation delay

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, angular-transitions

I'm trying to use `ng-animate` with an `ng-repeat` (and `ng-show`) to fade out old content and replace it with new.

The problem I'm having is that during the `remove` and `add` animations, both the element(s) being added and the element(s) being removed have `display:block`.

I thought I could avoid this by using an `animation-delay` in the CSS, but that just delays the fade, and not the addition of the class that sets `display` on the element.

The result is a jerky transition.

This is my animation CSS (cut down):

```
.keyframe-fade.ng-enter,
.keyframe-fade.ng-move {
  animation: 0.5s fade-in;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}
.keyframe-fade.ng-leave {
  animation: 0.5s fade-out;
}
```

But it's easier to demonstrate with [**this plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/QIxOcUMdw5TCOcG9VMFt?p=preview).

Any ideas?

**NOTE:** To be clear, the desired behaviour on the plunkr linked is that the coloured squares always take up the same space, i.e. they sit on the same line and the button doesn't move. If possible, I'd like to fix this without absolute positioning 'bodges' as the actual page I'm using this on is much more complex than the demo given.

Comment: Only one of the items needs to be absolute positioned - sometimes this can be useful to realize :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that I found for this is to augment the pure CSS animation with a very small amount of JavaScript.

To summarise the problem:

- The entering element is added to the DOM with the `ng-enter` class at the same time that the leaving element is given the `ng-leave` class.
- Though there is an animation delay, the entering element still takes up space

So this piece of javascript takes the element and adds `ng-hide` for the duration of the leave-animation, removing it afterwards.

```
.animation('.keyframe-fade', ['$timeout', function ($timeout){
  return {
    enter: function (element, done){

      // Add ng-hide for the duration of the leave animation.
      element.addClass('ng-hide');

      $timeout(function(){
        element.removeClass('ng-hide');
      }, 500)

      done();

    }
  }
}])
```

The duration is hard-coded here but I don't see any reason that you couldn't grab it from the element instead.

Improvements/suggestions welcomed.

Here's the original **[plunkr with the change](http://plnkr.co/edit/QPLUDRGPRstEkf8GR1K3?p=preview)**.

Comment: Avoid using setTimeouts to animate items in this manner. a CSS Callback would be much preferred. Depending on the performance necessities of the project and power of the device. In some cases, the timeout may complete before the animation is complete on slower devices.

Answer (score 1):

This is awful, and for Angular 2+ but just for the record here's one idea.

I have two `button` elements, one for when the user has items in their shopping cart, and one for when they don't.

The easiest way by far is to put `position: relative` on the parent DIV and `position: absolute` on both the buttons. The main disadvantage is the parent DIV has to be sized manually, and things like centering becoming trickier.

---

If the intent is to delay adding to the DOM based on an Observable value, then I thought '**Why not just delay the observable value?**' which will have the same end effect. This needs to be done only when the transition is from false > true though because you only want to hide it when it is coming *into* view. So I used a pipe to handle this.

```
    <!-- This button for when item is IN the cart -->
    <button [@cartIconAnimation] *ngIf="showCartIcon | delayTrue | async">View Cart</button>

    <!-- This button for when item is NOT IN the cart -->
    <button [@cartIconAnimation] *ngIf="showCartIcon | complement | delayTrue | async">Add to Cart</button>
```

This assumes `showCartIcon` is `Observable<boolean>`.

Then the pipes are as follows, and no delay is required on your animation criteria.

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'delayTrue'
})
export class DelayTruePipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor() {}

    transform(value: Observable<any> | any, delay: number): Observable<any> {
        if (isObservable(value)) {
            return value.pipe(distinctUntilChanged(), debounce((show) => show ? timer(delay || 500) : empty()));
        } else {
            throw Error('Needs to be an observable');
        }
    }
}

@Pipe({
    name: 'complement'
})
export class ComplementPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor() {}

    transform(value: Observable<boolean> | any): Observable<any> {
        if (isObservable(value)) {
            return value.pipe(map(i => !i));
        } else {
            throw Error('Needs to be an observable');
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The delay used by the pipe must be greater than the time it takes for the previous item to disappear, or you'll have the same problem.

The complement pipe just inverts the boolean value.

This solution works, but it's hacky and the timing might be harder to get wrong and there may be race conditions as two different browser timers fire off at the same time. I'd only do something like this if you really can't use `position: absolute`.

Comment: I should probably also point out that when using `position: absolute` that only one of the two items needs this positioning to avoid the problem. This helped me with my particular situation since one of the items was `width: 100%; height: 100%`